# Errors with classes

Tags: c++, class

I am creating a program, these are the requirements:

We are going to write a program to ﬁgure out if several elements are boiling or melting.

Substance---Melting Point---- Boiling Point

Zinc(Zn)--- (787.15°F)--------(1665°F)

Barium(Ba)- (1341°F)----------(3353°F)

Mercury(Hg)-(-37.89°F)------- (674.11°F)

Uranium(U)--(2070°F)----------( 7468°F)

Design a class that stores a temperature in a temperature member variable and has the appropriate accessor and mutator functions.

In addition to appropriate constructors, the class should have the following member functions for each of the elements:

• isZincMelting. This function should return the bool value true if the temperature stored in the temperature ﬁeld is at or above the melting point and below the boiling point of zinc. Otherwise, the function should return false.

• isZincBoiling. This function should return the bool value true if the temperature stored in the temperature ﬁeld is at or above the boiling point of zinc. Otherwise, the function should return false.

• Similarly you should have isBariumMelting, isBariumBoiling

• Similarly you should have isMercuryMelting, isMercuryBoiling

• Similarly you should have isUraniumMelting, isUraniumBoiling

Write a program that demonstrates the class.

The program should ask the user to enter a temperature, and then display a list of the substances that will melt at that temperature and those that will boil at that temperature.

For example, if the temperature is 1764 the class should report:

Zinc boils, Barium melts, Mercury boils and Uranium is solid

--This is what I have so far and I am getting some errors.
 *In function 'int main()':
 69:21: error: no matching function for call to 'Elements::isZincMelting()'
 69:21: note: candidate is:
 51:6: note: bool Elements::isZincMelting(float)
 51:6: note: candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
 In member function 'bool Elements::isZincMelting(float)':
 56:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]

Any help is appreciated. Thank you

```
#include<iostream> 
#include <cmath>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstdio>


using namespace std;

class Elements
{
    private:
        float temp;

    public:
        //float getTemp() const; //Get user temp
        void setTemp(float);
        bool isZincMelting(float);
        bool isZincBoiling(float);
        bool isBariumMelting(float);
        bool isBariumBoiling(float);
        bool isMercuryMelting(float);
        bool isMercuryBoiling(float);
        bool isUraniumMelting(float);
        bool isUraniumBoiling(float);


};
//setTemp
void Elements::setTemp(float temp)
{
        float t;
    getTemp = t;
}

bool Elements::isZincMelting( float t)
{
    if (t >= 787.15 && t < 1665)
        return true;

}

int main()
{
    Elements info; //Define an instance of Element class 
    float getTemp;

    cout << "Enter a temperature: " << endl;
    cin >> getTemp;

    //Store in temp of element info object
    info.setTemp(getTemp);

    info.isZincMelting();


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Read the error message again. Then read your code. Then the message. Then the code. And so on and so on until you understand the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

isZincMelting expects a float as argument you called it without arguments. Also your isZinMelting function should return false in if the condition is not met:

```
bool Elements::isZincMelting( float t)
{
    if (t >= 787.15 && t < 1665)
        return true;
    return false;

}
```